# Loop through a string and wrap each word in a div - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Im getting a websites "keywords" for my web ranker. Its returning the result I need, but I want to wrap each keyword its returning into a span tag.

This is how im  getting the keywords:

```
$websiteTags = get_meta_tags('http://www.'.$website.'/');

dd($websiteTags);
```

Which gives me this:[image: get_meta_tags results]

Them I just call the `$websiteTags['keywords'];` to get this result:

[image: Keywords]

I need to wrap each word in that string in a span tag so it will look nicer in the frontend, because right now its just putting out that long string.

My question is, how would I  loop through that string and wrap each keyword in a span tag.

I have tried doing foreach loops, str_replace() and looked online, but could not find the solution I need.

Comment: Is it really a string and not an array?

Comment: If you've tried "I have tried doing foreach loops, str_replace()", what went wrong? What kind of errors were you getting? **Why** was it not the solution you need? My approach would be something similar; looping over the words, checking if they're in the `keywords` array, replacing, etc etc.

Comment: I mean, its within an array, but Im pretty sure its a string right?

Comment: $result = explode(",",$websiteTags['keywords']) Loop the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Bas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2072433/bas) answer worked the best for me. I copied what he had:

```
 $keyword = explode(",",$websiteTags['keywords']);
```

Then in the frontend, I just did this:

```
@foreach($keyword as $key => $w)
        <span class="label label-success">{{ $w }}</span>
@endforeach
```

---

Also, [Alexey Mezenin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin) answer works too.

In backend:

```
$keyword = '<span class="label label-success">'.str_replace(', ', '</span><span class="label label-success">', $websiteTags['keywords']).'</span>';
```

Frontend:`{!! $keyword !!}`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this is you just want to wrap each word into `<span></span>`:

```
'<span>'.str_replace(', ', '</span><span>', $string).'</span>'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I tried this, but it was returning the actually <span> in text wrapped around each keyword, not the HTML code.

Comment: @David it's HTML, just use `{!! $string !!}}` instead of `{{ $string }}` for this string. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Ya, I forgot about that, Ill mention you in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = ['<span style="....">"%s"</span>' % x 
            for x in $websiteTags['keywords'];)
```

nb. $websiteTags['keywords'] is some string as defined in your question

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if it would work, but you could try placing your data in a database and query the data and use a while loop to echo the spans

Comment: if you are not sure just comment to the problem. And your answer will not work, because in DB will still be a string.

Comment: My bad. New to stack. Just an idea what came to my mind when I read over it. But isn't that the point? Tags are just keywords which are string values